# Remove unused references from all XAML files in a project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, refactoring

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional with Resharper. Right clicking on a project and selecting the option "Analyze and Code Cleanup" and then selecting "Run Code Cleanup (Profile 1)" does the job good but it does not touch XAML files in the project.

The same goes for the option "Refactor | Remove Unused References" in the context menu when right clicking a project. The unused references inside XAML are not removed.

Is there a way to also remove unused references from XAML files in the selected project ?
Executing the following shortcut <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>G</kbd> inside a XAML file does sort and remove unused references, but how can I execute this shortcut an all XAML files inside a Project/Solution ?

Resharper is shown below, but it does not remove unused references inside XAML files.
[image: resharper remove unused references]

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+Shift+R` and then choose *Remove Unused References* ?.

Comment: Or *Right-click the selection and choose Refactor | Remove Unused References in the context menu*.?

Comment: I delete unused `xmlns` manually. I am curious why are those critical? I tend to completely ignore leftover of such and even `using`. Intellisense will highlight unused anyway.

Comment: @Sinatr not critical but if you ask me unused references irritates me a lot ahaha :D

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain no this option too does not help.

Comment: @Sinatr i had to move some files from one project to another.  This caused some leftovers of references in XAML files which cause compile errors. Executing the Action remove all unused references in XAML Files in a project would solve this.

Comment: @Devid, then just go through all errors and fix each manually. When moving files manually you have to fix used references anyway apart from unused references .

Comment: @Sinatr there are a lot of views (used references are already fixed by resharper). Anyway the question is how can I execute this on all XAML files in a project at once.